# Was it common practice in 1940-60 to coat copper cold water pipe from the mains with a thick material that set up hard, possibly cementitious?

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to find out what is coating the outside of the 3/4 copper domestic cold water supply pipe in my basement. The house was built around 1950. The length of copper pipe that runs from an ell after the meter up to the floor joists above has been coated with some kind of very thick gunk, about 1/8" thick, possibly some kind of cementitious paint or just plain paint. A lot of it appears to have flaked off, and there are also some short sections of the pipe that do not have this gunk anywhere on them.  Was it common practice to coat that supply pipe from the mains, and if so what was the purpose?

[image: coated pipe1]
[image: coated pipe2]

Comment: maybe it is accidental

Comment: Is the back of the pipe (facing the wall) also coated?   If not, it was probably just a sloppy job at coating the wall.

Comment: @jay613: The rear side is not entirely free of it but it has far less, so I think you may be right. In the late 1980s, previous owners had the basement remediated after removal of rigid asbestos insulation from around the hydronic heating pipes, and that included painting the walls to encapsulate any asbestos fibers.

Comment: probably keeps it from sweating as much on humid days by insulating the metal some. Not common afaik, but not a bad idea if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

From your photos it looks like the same material as the walls. Some sort of masonry paint is my best guess.